# openpyxl error: got an unexpected keyword argument 'quotePrefix'

Tags: python, openpyxl

I've written a script that reads an .xlsx file using openpyxl on MacOS.
I made updates to allow my script to run on MacOS or Linux. Openpyxl is raising an error when calling `load_workbook`.

```
import platform
system = platform.system()

if system == "Darwin":
    cpgatt = "/Users/tlombard/desktop/py-sandbox/PickleJar/CSG_CHG_Clarity_attributes1.xlsx"
if system == 'Linux':
    cpgatt = "/ws/tlombard-sjc/Picklejar/CSG_CHG_Clarity_attributes1.xlsx"
cpgatt_wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(cpgatt)
```

The error I get is:

```
"TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'quotePrefix'"
The full traceback:-------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/auto/elb_hwtools/cae/lib/python/v2.7.8/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 149, in load_workbook
    _load_workbook(wb, archive, filename, read_only, keep_vba)
  File "/auto/elb_hwtools/cae/lib/python/v2.7.8/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 237, in _load_workbook
    keep_vba=keep_vba)
  File "/auto/elb_hwtools/cae/lib/python/v2.7.8/openpyxl/reader/worksheet.py", line 324, in read_worksheet
    fast_parse(ws, xml_source, shared_strings, style_table, color_index)
  File "/auto/elb_hwtools/cae/lib/python/v2.7.8/openpyxl/reader/worksheet.py", line 312, in fast_parse
    parser.parse()
  File "/auto/elb_hwtools/cae/lib/python/v2.7.8/openpyxl/reader/worksheet.py", line 93, in parse
    dispatcher[tag_name](element)
  File "/auto/elb_hwtools/cae/lib/python/v2.7.8/openpyxl/reader/worksheet.py", line 189, in parse_row_dimensions
    self.parse_cell(cell)
  File "/auto/elb_hwtools/cae/lib/python/v2.7.8/openpyxl/reader/worksheet.py", line 134, in parse_cell
    cell = Cell(self.ws, column, row, **style)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'quotePrefix'
>>> cpgatt
'/ws/tlombard-sjc/Picklejar/CSG_CHG_Clarity_attributes1.xlsx'
>>>
```

Comment: I'm having the same kind of error in one of my script. I think this comes from a number formatting that openpyxl can't parse.

Comment: Please submit a bug report with a full traceback and preferably a sample file.

Comment: Thank's Charlie- Here link to the bug report-  https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issue/438/linux-version-of-openpyxl-does-not-open

Comment: Thank you Charlie for the work-around suggestions.  I've down-reved openpyxl on the linux machine to 2.1.5   All is good.

Comment: @CharlieClark How do we submit a bug report, should we clone https://bitbucket.org/bugreport/openpyxl execute a pull request then commit a bug? I'm coming from a git hub background and I have been reading the Merc docs but this `hg clone` command is throwing me for a loop

Comment: @phillipsk reporting a bug has nothing to do with cloning the project. You just go to the bug/issue tracker and create a new one.

You only need to fork if you're going to make a pull request. AFAIK this is pretty much the same on Bitbucket as it is on Github. In both cases you fork on the site and then clone/download your fork to your machine to work on.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, here is my full trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__init__.py", line 318, in readExcelFile
    wb2 = load_workbook( unicode(self.ui_sourcePath.text()))#self.ui_sourcePath.text().replace("/",  "\\"))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 149, in load_workbook
    _load_workbook(wb, archive, filename, read_only, keep_vba)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 237, in _load_workbook
    keep_vba=keep_vba)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\worksheet.py", line 325, in read_worksheet
    fast_parse(ws, xml_source, shared_strings, style_table, color_index)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\worksheet.py", line 313, in fast_parse
    parser.parse()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\worksheet.py", line 93, in parse
    dispatcher[tag_name](element)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\worksheet.py", line 190, in parse_row_dimensions
    self.parse_cell(cell)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\worksheet.py", line 135, in parse_cell
    cell = Cell(self.ws, column, row, **style)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'quotePrefix'
```

As you can see in the trace, the error is occuring when openpyxl tries to parse the workbook. I added the following line in `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\worksheet.py` @135

```
column, row = coordinate_from_string(coordinate)
print column,  row
cell = Cell(self.ws, column, row, **style)
```

The problem came from one of the cell in my Excel workbook, and only one. My temporary solution to this problem is to delete de `quotePrefix` key in the `style` dict:

```
    style = {}
    if style_id is not None:
        style_id = int(style_id)
        style = self.styles[style_id]
        if "quotePrefix" in style.keys():
                del style["quotePrefix"]

    column, row = coordinate_from_string(coordinate)
    cell = Cell(self.ws, column, row, **style)
    self.ws._add_cell(cell)
```

I couldn't manage to find why this particular cell cause these problems and how to override a quote prefix.

Comment: Prior to 2.2 the styles were modelled directly but making them immutable made them slow. 2.2 maps the pointers to the various style settings directly to "styleable" objects (cells, rows, columns). This is faster and safe from unintended consequences but doesn't yet take all the possibilities into consideration. `quotePrefix` and `pivotButton` are implicit formatting options with no direct analogue in the GUI.

Deleting them will prevent the exception but will also remove the styling. As long as you only need the data then using read-only mode is probably the best workaround until a fix.